# SonarQube issues : Have a boolean and Sonar tells me to make it "final"

Tags: static, sonarqube, boolean

When I make it "final", Sonar tells me to make it static too. 
I don't want both of those 2 recommandations. How can I do to just have this for my boolean :
private boolean myBoolean = true; ???

Comment: Please add the whole context (whole class). It is impossible to solve your problem without seeing the code.

Comment: Maybe you don't like this rule in your context. Have a look at the rules checked and maybe you can disable it.